# Binary search ordered array issue

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, binary-search

```
int arr[] = {21, 44, 56, 76, 89, 91, 102, 120, 143, 167, 242, 291}; //array.length == 11.
int goal = 143;
int i = (arr.length - 1)/2;
int upper = arr.length -1;
int lower = 0;
int found = 0;
boolean foundYes = false;
int j;
while (foundYes = false) {
    if(arr[i] > goal) {
        upper = i;
        i = (upper - lower)/2;
    } else if(arr[i] < goal) {
        lower = i;
        i = (upper - lower)/2;
    } else if(arr[i] == goal) {
        found = i;
        foundYes = true;
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(found);
```

**I'm trying to find the index in the array for which the value is 143. So arr[x] = 143, where finding x is the goal**

I tried the debugger with break points, but it doesnt give me much info or detail.

**What I got from the debugger:** So it detected that `arr[i] == arr[5] == 91 < 143` but it never changes anything and the found is returned as `found==0` What is the issue here?

**EDIT:** I've got it working:

```
   int arr[] = {21, 44, 56, 76, 89, 91, 102, 120, 143, 167, 242, 291}; //array.length == 11.
    int goal = 143;
    int i = (arr.length - 1)/2; //first arr[i] = 91.
    int upper = arr.length -1;
    int lower = 0;
    int found = 0;
    boolean foundYes = false;
    int j;
    while (foundYes == false) {
        if(arr[i] > goal){
            upper = i;
            i = upper + (upper - lower)/2;
        }
        else if(arr[i] < goal){
            lower = i;
            i = lower + (upper - lower)/2;
        }
        else if(arr[i] == goal){
             found = i;
            foundYes = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(found);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you expand on what exactly you are trying to do and what exactly is going wrong with it?

Comment: @jcolemang, I'm trying to find the index in the array for which the value is 143. So arr[x] = 143, where finding x is the goal. It's just returning 0 all the time.

Comment: In the future try to include that information in your question, that is probably the reason for the down votes.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues. First, your syntax in the `while` is incorrect, which is why your program is not being sent into an infinite loop. You want `foundYes == false`, not `foundYes = false`. The second issue (which you may not have come across yet) is how you are setting `i`. Suppose `upper` were equal to `8` and `lower` were equal to `7`. What does `i` become? Look at that and see if you can figure it out from there.